# jQuery Tabs; cookie trouble

Tags: jquery, tabs, cookies

I'm having trouble finding out how to set jQuery cookie for my tabs on this page: http://onomadesign.com/wordpress/identity-design/alteon-a-boeing-company/

My jQuery Tabs code is like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.sc_menu_wrapper > div');

    $('a.tab').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

        $('a.tab').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});});
```

So what piece of code do I need to make the last selected tab visible when visitors click on a different project. In other words: when people select a project from 'industry' tab, it should stay open on the next page.

I'm kinda lost here, any help would be great. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand your problem but anyway here goes...

What you can do is hook up to tab clicked event (called `select`) and write a code to record the index, name or whatever that will allow you to identify the tab in a cookie. Then once your page refreshes and tabs are loaded again you can have a code to check if a cookie with this recorded value is present and force this tab to be displayed (with `select` method).

Notice the difference between `select` event handler [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) and `select` method [link here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select).

Comment: Thankyou. Yes I indeed want to force the page to display the tab with 'selected' class, from the cookie. 

But what is my code gonna be? I am really a noob programmer, I'm sorry. Could you paste in here the exact code that I should put in the php page?